# In Oracle apex 20.2, What is the javascript to get the selected tree node id

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

Good day,

I am running orcl apex 20.2. I have a tree region with a simple table: id, title, parent_id.

I am struggling with the JS to get the selected node id, and store it in a page item.  My JS skills are very week.  I have been trying to use a dynamic Action to execute JS and use a treeNodeAdapter, but the object returned is a jQuery object.  I have no idea what to do at that point.

Given the table above, can someone please write back the exact JS I would need in the DA to capture the selected id and save it to the page item...

Pls & thnx

Nikita

Comment: LittleFoot, thnx for the help.  I did try this, but just kept getting JS error on the page.  I will try again to see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how (based on Scott's `EMP` table).

Suppose it is page 70 which contains the tree region. Create a page item on it (for example, `P70_EMPNO`).

The tree query looks like this (pay attention to the `link` column; once clicked, it stores the selected node value into the `P70_EMPNO` page item):

```
select 
  case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0 when level = 1 then 1 else -1 end as status,
  level,
  ename || ' (' || empno ||')' as title,
  'icon-tree-folder' as icon,
  empno as value,
  ename as tooltip,
  --
  'javascript:$s(''P70_EMPNO'', '''||EMPNO||''')' as link        --> this
from emp
start with mgr is null
connect by prior empno = mgr
order siblings by ename;
```

The result (when you click on the `JAMES` node):

[image]

---

P.S. It looks that your keyboard is broken; quite a few letters are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave your Tree Building Query as it is and use the Tree-Region attributes to save the ID in an Apex Item. You just have to define Link like screenshots below:
Assuming `ID` is set as `Node Value Column` and `P1_REPORT_ID` is the Page Item where the selected node value should be set, then your Link Target should be: 
`Type: URL` and 
`URL`:`javascript:apex.item("P1_REPORT_ID").setValue(&ID.)`

You can set Link activation for single/double click. 
Now you can define `on Change` Dynamic Action on `P1_REPORT_ID` and do whatever you need with the selected ID (=P1_REPORT_ID) 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eKF7.png)

[JS as URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0izb2.png)

Comment: Please include everything required to understand the answer in a text form without relying on external resources

Comment: Excuse me, if my answer wasn't clear enough.
I assumed that Nikita has the SQL-Query and Apex Tree. That's why I tried to explain, how it is possible to save the selected node value (ID) in an Apex Page Item.

**I didn't get, what you meant by "relying on external resources". SORRY!!
But if you meant the Links- "Screenehot" and "JS as URL", then I would recommend you to click on the Links and it should help you to understand how and where to set what.
Those Links are not external, StackOverflow attached them as external Link, as I don't have enough points to embed Image in  post.